# how to apply css on dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor, razorengine

Hy... I am working on @Html.Dropdownlist. When I run this code without bootstrap class, I can see default text on my screen. But I can't see default text on screen when I apply bootstrap class.

```
@Html.DropDownList("Time", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem {Text = "08:30-10:00", Value="1", Selected = true},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "10:00-11:30", Value="2"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "11:30-01:00", Value="3"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "01:00-02:30", Value="4"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "02:30-04:00", Value="5"},
    new SelectListItem {Text = "04:00-05:30", Value="6"}
}, "Select Time", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModulesEdit.ProjectID, 
   new SelectList(ViewBag.FillProject, "ProjectID", "ProjectName"),
   "--Select--",
   new { @style = "color:black;", @class = "form-control", id = "ddlProjectName" })
```

Comment: I am not using model here. its just a dropdownlist

Comment: my code is working perfectly but just its not showing text